# Syncing local git repo using Dropbox

Tags: git, github, dropbox

[Numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199637/is-it-possible-to-host-a-bare-git-repository-using-dropbox-to-share-code) make it clear that using a shared Dropbox folder as a git remote can lead to problems.

However, [opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507098/using-dropbox-as-local-git-working-repo) [seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762409/github-and-dropbox-conflict-risk) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819362/using-git-and-dropbox-on-different-machines-without-problems) [mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086611/git-and-dropbox-local-repo) about placing a local repository (e.g. cloned from Github) into a private Dropbox folder.

My question is twofold:

1) Is it dangerous to place a local repository in a private Dropbox folder (that syncs across multiple computers, all owned by me)?

2) Is my remote repo (on GitHub) in danger if a *collaborator* chooses to sync their local repository to Dropbox (i.e. a collaborator clones the repository to Dropbox and regularly commits and pushes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer putting a [git bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633346/6309) (a compressed version of your Git repo, one you can clone) in a Dropbox folder.

Putting a full Git repo into Dropbox remains risky, as [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309).

But should a collaborator do so, pushing to it would not influence the upstream GitHub repo, nor would it influence your own Dropbox-managed version of that repository.